# what's the best app to draw UI wireframes on the mac? (And why)

Tags: macos, user-interface, wireframe

I want to draw user interfaces for web and desktop applications.

I need something less print-oriented than omnigraffle. think pixels!

Also, need good building blocks (aka stencils). Form elements, tableviews, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I've been playing around with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/) and it's OK for basic wireframes. I still prefer pen and paper sketches that are later refined in Photoshop when working on my own, but Balsamiq is useful when working in a team.

Answer (score 4):

[WireframeSketcher wireframing tool](http://wireframesketcher.com) comes with fast and native UI on Mac. It works well with retina display too. There is a large built-in library of controls and extra stencils are available.

[image: WireframeSketcher on Mac screenshot]

Comment: +1 for the effort of providing a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I very much like [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/Omnigraffle/), with [stencils](http://v1.garrettdimon.com/resources/templates-stencils-for-visio-omnigraffle) for UI design. More UI stencils are [also available](http://graffletopia.com/categories/user-interface).

You might also check some [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643) [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86234) on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest - I find Interface Builder just as fast as using Omnigraffle with (the aforementioned) stencils for prototyping desktop application UIs.

Plus the bonus is you get *all* of the available controls to look at.

Comment: I have to tell you I've done that a few times already, but seems... awkward?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of Illustrator, InDesign is actually better because you can  do multipage layouts and use master pages for constants like headers/nav etc...

Answer (score 2):

Axure just released Axure RP 5.6 for mac in Alpha. Great for websites and apps. http://axure.com/CS/blogs/axure/archive/2009/12/22/6104.aspx

You can also pair OmniGraffle with the free Web UX Template from Konigi.com

Answer (score 1):

All these answers, and nobody has mentioned the grandaddy of them all?

Use Adobe Illustrator!

Create your own stencils / reusable components in layers and share those between documents.

Answer (score 1):

Sharpie and paper first.

Then MAYBE illustrator to show detail close-ups if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With anything except Interface Builder you're going to have to get the standard UI control templates from somewhere else or make them yourself.

I've been using [Lineform](http://www.freeverse.com/apps/app/?id=6020), which turns out to be pretty good at specifying dimensions in Pixels (just select "Points / Pixels" as the Measurement Unit in Lineform Preferences).  That was something I had trouble doing in older versions of OmniGraffle (haven't used it lately though).

Answer (score -3):

Try [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/). It seems to be one of the best kept secrets for simple drawing and image manipulation on the Mac. I heard about it recently on TMO Geek Gab podcast.